# Select box with 'Other' option to display input text field. How to get value back for form submission using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, textfield, drop-down-menu

I've got a form with the following select box:

```
<fieldset id="workers_comp_info">
  <p>
    <label for="i_n_r_reason">Reason why Workers Comp Insurance is not required:</label>
    <select name="i_n_r_reason" id="i_n_r_reason">
      <option value="No employees">No employees</option>
      <option value="1-2 employees">1-2 employees</option>
      <option value="Other">Other(Specify reason)</option>
    </select>
    <input id="other_reason" name="other_reason" type="text" placeholder="Other Reason" />
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

I've written the following jquery code to hide the "other_reason" text field unless "Other" is selected in the select box.

```
$('#i_n_r_reason').change(function() {
  $('#other_reason').toggle($(this).val()=='Other');
}).change();
```

I am creating a jquery method called SubmitForm.  I want to write something like this:

```
function SubmitForm() {
  if ($('#i_n_r_reason').val()=='Other')
    ('#i_n_r_reason').val = ('#other_reason').val
  ('#account_form').submit();
}
```

When the user selects 'Other', the text field is displayed for them to enter a reason.  I want this reason to override 'Other' when the user submits the form. But its not happening with this code.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

xar's answer has some sweet functionality, but it doesn't accomplish the original goal of replacing the value of #i_n_r_reason with the value of #other_reason when "Other" is selected. I put it all together below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //initially hide the textbox
            $("#other_reason").hide();
            $('#i_n_r_reason').change(function() {
              if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "Other"){
                $("#other_reason").show();
              }else{
                $("#other_reason").hide();
              }
            });
            $("#other_reason").keyup(function(ev){
                var othersOption = $('#i_n_r_reason').find('option:selected');
                if(othersOption.val() == "Other")
                {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    //change the selected drop down text
                    $(othersOption).html($("#other_reason").val()); 
                } 
            });
            $('#form_id').submit(function() {
                var othersOption = $('#i_n_r_reason').find('option:selected');
                if(othersOption.val() == "Other")
                {
                    // replace select value with text field value
                    othersOption.val($("#other_reason").val());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.perfectweb.com/resources/post.php" id="form_id" method="post">
    <fieldset id="workers_comp_info">
      <p>
        <label for="i_n_r_reason">Reason why Workers Comp Insurance is not required:</label>
        <select name="i_n_r_reason" id="i_n_r_reason">
          <option value="No employees">No employees</option>
          <option value="1-2 employees">1-2 employees</option>
          <option value="Other">Other(Specify reason)</option>
        </select>
        <input id="other_reason" name="other_reason" type="text" placeholder="Other Reason" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <input id="form_submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //initially hide the textbox
            $("#other_reason").hide();
            $('#i_n_r_reason').change(function() {
              if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "Other"){
                $("#other_reason").show();
              }else{
                $("#other_reason").hide();
              }
            });
            $("#other_reason").keyup(function(ev){
                  var othersOption = $('#i_n_r_reason').find('option:selected');
                  if(othersOption.val() == "Other"){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    //change the selected drop down text
                    $(othersOption).html($("#other_reason").val()); 


                  } 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset id="workers_comp_info">
      <p>
        <label for="i_n_r_reason">Reason why Workers Comp Insurance is not required:</label>
        <select name="i_n_r_reason" id="i_n_r_reason">
          <option value="No employees">No employees</option>
          <option value="1-2 employees">1-2 employees</option>
          <option value="Other">Other(Specify reason)</option>
        </select>
        <input id="other_reason" name="other_reason" type="text" placeholder="Other Reason" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically what it does is :

When the dropdown's changing, evaluate the value. If it's "Others" then show the textbox, else hide it.

For the second part, upon submitting the form, evaluate the value of the selected drop down. If it's "Others", then prevent the form from submitting, instead change the text of the selected drop down list to the value from the text box.

I guess the code is pretty explainable. Hope this helps.

**EDITED**

Comment: Thanks, the show and hide don't really seem to hide the box.  The option I'm using with the toggle() does work however.  And it doesn't appear that I can override the value of a select box.

Comment: @user338413 : The code works fine here. I just updated my answer and show the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SubmitForm() {
  if ($('#i_n_r_reason').val()=='Other')
    ('#i_n_r_reason').val = ('#other_reason').val
  ('#account_form').submit();
}
```

is that an exact copy of your current code? or a quick rewrite? there are so many things missing!!

i'm not sure you can set the value of a select box to something that isn't an option.   what you could do is have a hidden field that stores the value of the select or the value of your extra textbox.

so in your change() function on your select. set the value of the hidden field to the value of the select with something like:

```
$('#MyHiddenField').val($(this).val());
```

and in your form submit function do this:

```
if ($('#i_n_r_reason').val()=='Other'){
 $('#MyHiddenField').val($('#MyHiddenField').val());
}
```

Comment: I'm using a hidden field now but I'm having an issue of grabbing the value from it. I'm going to post this question again with the new code.